# How to enhance text and line drawing scan in photoshop?

Tags: adobe-photoshop, scanning, photography, line-art, filter

I have photographed text and writing with usual camera. Picture contains black printing lines and blue pen writing.

Picture contains the following artifacts:

1) paper is not white

2) non-uniform shading over paper

3) irregular paper pattern

Are there conventional ways to enhance such an images automatically? I wish paper to become uniformly white, without pattern, printing will be close to perfect black and writing close to perfect blue.

Comment: This might help you http://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/7961/poor-quality-signature-from-paper-to-computer

Comment: The referenced question/answer is how I would do it too.

Comment: Agreed, although it needs a better question headline...

Comment: Best way to get help on this type of question is to actually post part of the pic.  Typically someone will take it into PS and then post a step-by-step solution using your actual pic (which is exactly what you're asking for).

Answer (score 2):

If you can keep consistent lighting in the photographs, for example, by having the same light point at the table and place the camera somewhere so you know you can always shoot the image in the same conditions, you could record *Curves* or *Levels* **Action** to do this (I would suggest Curves, since you want to have pretty exact results.) Then you could just open up all the images, use **Batch..** and apply the recorded Action to the images.

If you're not familiar with Curves, I suggest you take a look at this tutorial, it covers the effect pretty well.
http://psd.fanextra.com/tutorials/professional-retouching-tutorial-using-curves-in-photoshop-part-3/

Heres a video about recording Actions:
http://video.about.com/graphicssoft/Quick-Tip--How-to-Record-and-Save-Actions-in-Photoshop-CS6.htm

Heres nice little tutorial on how to use Batch:
http://www.dummies.com/how-to/content/how-to-batch-process-actions-in-photoshop-cs6.html

So, you just combine these three with the premise that your photos actually have similiar color values to begin with (even if they vary a little, your results might be acceptable) and you're done.