# How do I make this signature look more high-quality?

Tags: adobe-photoshop

[image]

How can I make this image a higher quality? It looks like a low quality image right now and I can't seem to figure how to fix that. I use Photoshop for my editing, but suggestions on other platforms would be appreciated too.

Comment: You obviously have tried to enhance something, but made it worse. Show to us the original in high resolution and good light. then it's possible to say something useful. Now we cannot know what is the problem. For example now it's well possible that your image is exact and you actually want some guidance to your pen handling or hangover suppression.

Comment: Probably a duplicate of https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/q/7961/30216

Comment: Quite honestly I *would not* try and improve it. It looks real, natural, and non-digital -- all pluses when it comes to signatures.

Comment: Woah. Didn't expect this many replies so quick - thanks, guys. @user287001 I used the pen tool in Photoshop to trace a real-life signature I took a picture of. I have no clue how it came out this bad, but yeah, it did. I can post a picture of the original image, but this one signature is made up out of multiple attempts, not just tracing one signature.

Comment: If you show a good image, we maybe could say how to extract the ink as a shape which has transparent background.

Comment: Realize that you can't remove the image once you've posted it. It stays int eh system. By hiding it in your question all you are doing is making the question seem illogical and unhelpful to any future visitors (but the image is still on the StackExchange system). In short, there's **zero** benefit to trying to remove the image after it's been posted.

Answer (score 1):

Take a black ink pen that gives a lot of ink and write the signature several times on white paper.

Select the best signature and take a pic with your phone or digital camera, well lit, from within 1 foot.

Open it in photoshop and adjust levels or isolate color channels until you get one that looks very contrasty and crisp. 
Use this to mask out the signature.

Save as your favorite file type.

Answer (score 0):

Like Scott said, I wouldn't try and improve it any further, the current one looks **legitimate** and that legitimate look is very professional (in my opinion) compared to those digital ones that look like (and I've seen that some actually are..) a typed cursive font.

The image trace feature in Adobe Illustrator could also help, it works best with basic stroke & outline images.